# Unable to compile CMake

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I am trying to compile cmake and can't figure out how to add extra "-l" flags.

First, I run bootstrap, which seems to use "make" to compile a temporary version version of "cmake". Then, I am suppose to run "make", which will use the temporary cmake to make the "full version" of cmake.

However, on this second step, build is failing around 80% on this line:

```
/usr/sbin/g++ CMakeFiles/cmake.dir/cmakemain.cxx.o CMakeFiles/cmake.dir/cmcmd.cxx.o  -o ../bin/cmake libCMakeLib.a libCMakeServerLib.a \
libCMakeLib.a kwsys/libcmsys.a -ldl /usr/lib/libexpat.a /usr/lib/libz.a /usr/lib/libarchive.a /usr/lib/libcurl.a ../Utilities/cmjsoncpp/libcmjsoncpp.a \
/usr/lib/libuv.a ../Utilities/cmlibrhash/libcmlibrhash.a -lpthread
```

It's solved by adding the missing libraries at the end:

```
/usr/sbin/g++ CMakeFiles/cmake.dir/cmakemain.cxx.o CMakeFiles/cmake.dir/cmcmd.cxx.o  -o ../bin/cmake libCMakeLib.a libCMakeServerLib.a \
libCMakeLib.a kwsys/libcmsys.a -ldl /usr/lib/libexpat.a /usr/lib/libz.a /usr/lib/libarchive.a /usr/lib/libcurl.a ../Utilities/cmjsoncpp/libcmjsoncpp.a \
/usr/lib/libuv.a ../Utilities/cmlibrhash/libcmlibrhash.a -lpthread -lssl -llzma -lz -lcrypto
```

So HOW do I tell make/cmake to add the missing libraries at the end? I have tried all standard ways to do this and none works:

```
LIBS="..." make
CXXFLAGS="..." make
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="..." make
```

Comment: Did you try adding them after calling `make` like this: `make LIBS='-lssl -llzma -lz -lcrypto'` ?

Comment: Yes, still not being added.

Comment: You probably want to set `LDFLAGS` *before* running the bootstrap script. Try `export LDFLAGS='-lssl -llzma -lz -lcrypto'`, then in the same command window, run bootstrap from scratch.

Comment: what   version of cmake?

Comment: version is 3.15.5